# Package management on Erlang and Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, rebar, elixir-mix, relx

I searched for `package management` on `Erlang` and `Elixir` and got some pointers to `rebar` `rebar3` `mix` `hex` and `relx` etc. Can you help clarify the relationships among them? Where to use what? Is `package` just synonym to Erlang's `application` made up of `modules`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A package is synonym to Erlang or Elixir application/ library made up of one or more modules

Hex is currently the preferred package manager for the Erlang ecosystem (ERLANG, LFE, JOXA & ELIXIR)

**rebar3 + hex.pm:** For Erlang package management rebar3 uses hex.pm, a package manager for Erlang and Elixir packages. [more Documentation](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/hex-package-management)

**mix + hex.pm:** For Elixir package management mix uses hex.pm, a package manager for Erlang and Elixir packages. [more Documentation](https://hex.pm/docs/usage)

Comment: To add a little extra info to @byaruhaf's answer, `rebar3` is a new and improved `rebar`, `relx` is a release management tool, not package management, so you can safely ignore that in this context.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to everything @byaruhaf mentioned, `erlang.mk` provides simple package index functionality that allows for basic management of Erlang dependencies. It's very primitive compared with hex but it might be all you need. If your already have a Makefile for your project erlang.mk is probably the quickest way to add basic package management functionality to your project.

https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk#packages